# Error while calling js library using $var in a Python app

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

In my python code using web.py, I am trying to call js library in main layout.

Here is the code snippet -

$var js: static/js/jquery-3.4.0.min.js static/js/bootstrap.min.js static/js/material.min.js

However, when I execute the code it gives me this error:

127.0.0.1:51225 - - [04/May/2019 07:05:29] "HTTP/1.1 GET /âModels/js1/bootstrap.min.js"" - 404 Not Found

I have also added screenshot of the code and folder structure as attachment. What I can see is that during the call to library, it adds the special characters â and then instead of single quotes there are double quotes at the end. I suspect this is the problem for the library not found.

I was thinking that this could be because of UTF-8 issues. Hence i went and also updated the encoding standards to UTF-8 both at server and client level. But even this is not solving the problem. Can someone please help with suggestions here. I have been struggling this from last 4-5 days and trying to research everything that could help but not of much use.

I'm using PyCharm for development.

The js library path is correct and it should have been called. If it calls then my js code will be executed. Please suggest if I'm doing something wrong here.